# Force wait a function before the execution of next function Angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous, async-await

I want to wait for a function before my execution goes on. How do I do this

```
openOrganizationDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(NewOrganizationComponent, {
      width: '800px',
      height: '600px',
      data: {
        view: 'dialog'
      }
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(async result => {

      // Want to wait on below line, so that my list gets updated

      await this.getOrganizations();
      let organizationPreSelectId = this.organizationList[0].orginizationId;
      this.newLoanForm.patchValue({
        orginizationId: organizationPreSelectId
      });

    });
  }
```

and here is the function I'm talking about

```
async getOrganizations() {
    await this.organizationService.getOrganizations().subscribe((response) => {
      this.organizationList = response;
      this.organizationList.sort((a, b) => (a.orginizationId < b.orginizationId) ? 1 : -1);
    });
  }
```

I already tried `async await` but it's not working.
Thanks in advance to helping hands.

Comment: Awaiting a subscription isn't going to do anything; either return an observable or convert it toPromise and handle that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to convert your observable to a promise so that it will wait.

```
async getOrganizations() {
    this.organizationList = await this.organizationService.getOrganizations().toPromise();
    this.organizationList.sort((a, b) => (a.orginizationId < b.orginizationId) ? 1 : -1);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html

Comment: Worked like a magic Man, can you please tell me why my code was not working.

Comment: I think there are several reasons. One is that calling subscribe() returns a subscription, not an observable. Also await is wanting a promise, not an observable : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-7.html

Comment: `toPromise` waits for subscription completion - https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/91c5fc2faae5e29fedaef5a3aa5d2d20cdac4bce/src/internal/Observable.ts#L370. it's always safer with this approach to use pipe that provides subscription completion on first element, like `.pipe(take(1))` and secures method against 'improvements'. of course name `getOrganizations()` implies that there will be only one element, but if so, why its not a Promise already? Its better practise to use `this.organizationService.getOrganizations().pipe(take(1)).toPromise()` here.